# Why do people say that king is a god?

Tags: scripture

Kings are called gods by people and even in hinduism. People consider their monarchs as gods.

My question is why, a king is a god according to people in hinduism?

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m15/m15009.htm

> Like the illustrious Brahman himself, the Lord of the universe of creatures, this Yudhishthira of mighty energy will rule you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the scriptures a king is regarded as an incarnation of the [Ashta Dikpalas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_directions). That's why he is regarded and respected like God.

> **Manu Smriti 5.96. A king is an incarnation of the eight guardian deities of the world, the Moon, the Fire, the Sun, the Wind, Indra,
> the Lords of wealth and water (Kubera and Varuna), and Yama.**
>
> 5.97. Because the king is pervaded by those lords of the world, no impurity is ordained for him; for purity and impurity of mortals is
> caused and removed by (those) lords of the world.