# What's the significance of bathing a King's waist with mud sourced from a Prostitute-brothel?

Tags: rituals, symbolism, kings

In the  Agni Mahā-Purāṇa, we have verses in reference to the procedure of a King's coronation ceremony.

In the rituals involving cleansing the "to-be King's" body, we get the following -

[Chapter 218](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083447.html) - Rājābhiṣeka

> वेश्याद्वारमृदा राज्ञः कटिशौचं विधीयते । २१८.१६.क ।
>
> > 16. a. **It is laid down that the waist of a king should be cleansed with the mud (obtained) from the threshold of a courtesan,**

I seek the significance of this act. Or any specific symbolism behind this.

Is this connected to/ similar to the popular notion of sourcing the soil for goddess Durgā's idol from a courtesan's land,
 as discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/248/soil-for-maa-durga-puja), because a King is said to be [equivalent to the divinities](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49688/why-do-people-say-that-king-is-a-god)?

##### Which other scriptures besides the Agni Purāṇa, discuss this? And what's exactly the significance of this ritual?

Comment: I am just speculating. Generally the doer only bears the responsibility of sinful activities committed by him/her (exceptions are in case of extreme cases) but kings are said to bear responsibility for sinful activities commited by their subjects & the subjects are also said to bear the punishment inflicted by the divinities over the king. Perhaps the consecration by brothel soil was used to link the king & his subjects via sin.